# Is there a feminine equivalent for the word "houseman"?

Tags: word-usage, word-request, british-english, gender

There are lots of words ending with the masculine suffix -man. So far, I haven't had any trouble with their feminine equivalents (most of them can be easily found in dictionaries).

Now I *am* having a trouble with the Brittish word [*"houseman"*](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/houseman?fallbackFrom=british-grammar) meaning *" a male or female doctor who is still training, and who works in a hospital"*. I very much doubt that "housewoman" (or house (-) woman) might work at all in the meaning I'm going to use it.

So, is there a feminine equivalent for the word "houseman" like it is for the words chairman, horseman, postman, etc?

Since in AmE the synonym for the word *houseman* is *intern*, could it be possible to say a woman/girl intern or intern(n)ess, if the word exists at all?

Comment: 'Intern' is gender neutral, like 'bartender' and unlike 'stewardess'.

Comment: I've never come across the term. It sounds more like AmE. British hospital doctors are normally called *junior doctors*, *registrars* and *consultants* (in order of seniority).

Comment: @MickSharpe - Every dictionary I looked up the word in marks it as a BrE usage, [this](https://www.vocabulary.com/dictionary/houseman) for one.

Comment: I've never heard **houseman** used in the US. We would tend to say "female intern". https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=female+intern%2Cwoman+intern&year_start=1980&year_end=2008&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cfemale%20intern%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cwoman%20intern%3B%2Cc0  BTW, when I cite ngram, it's to corroborate my opinion as a native speaker, not to form it.

Comment: @TRomano - Thank you very much for the comment, but still the word does exist : "They had a son and lived in the UK for a couple of years, where Watsa worked as a hospital houseman and registrar."
BBCJul 21, 2014 (from the vocabulary.com site's multiple example sentences with it).

Comment: Maybe the term is used inside the profession. Lay-people call recently-qualified medical students "junior doctors". Anyway, it doesn't answer the OP's question.

Comment: The -ess feminine ending is used more often in British English than in American. In AmE we do not say **manageress** for example. The -ess ending and the -woman ending are now being deliberately avoided by many speakers of AmE. Actresses have become actors, chairwomen have become chairs, stewardesses, flight attendants. But  **princesses** remain princesses.

Comment: @TRomano - Thanks a lot. Even if you didn't like the question, your comment has been gratefully taken note of. I did have at least one upvote before it appeared, though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure why you want a "feminine equivalent." The trend these days is to use gender neutral terms (*flight attendant* instead of either *steward* or *stewardess*).

If you must stipulate the gender, you  can say *a female intern*. *Woman intern* would be less likely. And since *girl*, when applied to a female over 17, is seen as sexist by many but not all, I'd stay clear of that. Likewise *intern(n)ess* would come  across as sexist, like *stewardess*. (Some people even avoid using *actress*.)

Note you  could also just invent the word "homewoman". Presumably your context would show you are trying to use a "feminine equivalent" to *houseman*.  English is not limited to what's in dictionaries, but to those who write in the language. That's why neologisms, or new words & expressions,  are always possible.

---

Additional information:

Words ending  with *-man* are not necessarily "masculine  words". For instance, *Fortune* magazine reports:

[Exclusive: From AOL Exec to Antarctic Explorer, Meet National Geographic's First Female Chairman](http://fortune.com/2016/02/11/jean-case-national-geographic/)

This usage also leads support to the term *female intern* and not *woman intern*.

Indeed, [Oxford dictionary](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/chairman) reports that such "gender-neutral terns" as *chair* and *chairperson* are "far less common than chairman."

Last, simply FYI (for your information), instead of *houseman* you can  use *[house  officer](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/house_officer)*:

> A qualified doctor practising under supervision in hospital in the first year after graduation.

Both  *houseman* and  *house officer* are "British"  or "chiefly British."

Comment: Thanks for trying to help, Alan, but I'm afraid you didn't quite get what my request is for, and judging by the edit you've just made, you still don't. I'm sorry for that. Anyway, I never downvote answers to my questions, so believe me it wasn't me.

Comment: You can say "a woman/girl intern or intern(n)ess" If  for some reason you must stipulate the sex; you can also say "homewoman". Presumably your context would show you are trying to use a "feminine equivalent" to *houseman*. English is not limited to what's in dictionaries, but to those who write in the language.

Comment: Now you're answering my question. Why not do it in the right place - the answer box, ah?

Comment: Answer overhauled.

Comment: Thanks a lot, Alan, for an in-depth answer I liked very much. I was hoping to find something like this on the net but just couldn't.

Comment: NB: In British English usage an "intern" is almost always understood to be someone far far less skilled than a house doctor (who is qualified, albeit supervised). I have a lot of medics in the family and have never heard any of them refer to a qualified doctor as an intern.